# Average coefficients of several logistic regression models

Tags: classification, ensemble-learning

I trained M logistic regression models by randomly sampling original data. Now, I would like to combine the models. One way to combine is to perform majority voting on the output of predictions. I am thinking of another way of model averaging - by averaging the coefficients of my M logistic regression models.
Does it make sense? Are there any approaches in the literature that tried this?

Comment: Averaging might work for certain circumstances where the model is an excellent fit and sample sizes are large.  But, since it's not hard to think of other circumstances where averaging would be a particularly poor procedure, why not just fit a single model to all the data?

Comment: In addition to @whuber averaging of coefficients is very difficult to interpret if you have different variables in each model. On another note, resampling methods such as bootstrapping sound like what you are doing/trying to do. So you might want to look into that.

Comment: Are there any works done on that? I would like to understand if it generally makes sense from the theoretical point of view. 
Why is it difficult to interpret this averaging?

Comment: @whuber isn't this just bootstrapping the regression coefficients?

Comment: @ssdecontrol I don't believe majority voting could be framed as a form bootstrapping.  But yes, averaging the coefficients could be construed as a part of a bootstrapping process, assuming the "randomly sampling original data" was carried out in a bootstrapping fashion: that is, by taking pseudosamples of the same size as the original data, uniformly with replacement.  Note that bootstrapping would not use the averages of the coefficients directly: it would adjust them according to bootstrapping principles.